# Flex 3: Usuing a repeater & sending XML information to a component... havng some issues

Tags: xml, apache-flex, components

I trying to import an XML file, and send bits and pieces to a custom component.

My XML file is structured like this:

```
<projects>
  <project>
        <projName>{Insert title of project here}</projName>
        <startDate>{Insert date here}</startDate>
        <positions>
              <daysOffset>{Insert a number here}</daysOffset>
              <numDays>{Insert a number here}</daysOffset>
              <role>{Insert role here}</role>
              <student>{Insert name here}</student>
        </positions>
        // There can be an unlimited amount of positions listed
  </project>
  // There can be an unlimited amount of projects listed
```

I read in the XML data by using the following command:

```
<mx:XML id="projectsXML" xmlns="" source="xml/projects.xml" format="e4x" />
```

After the XML is imported, I try to use a repeater to send the information within each  tag to a custom component.  My code is below:

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="95%" x="0" y="80">
    <mx:Repeater id="projectRP" dataProvider="{projectsXML}">
        <Block:project 
            oneDay="{usableSize.width/14}" 
            projectTitle="{projectRP.currentItem.project.projName}"
            projectDate="{projectRP.currentItem.project.startDate}"
            projectPositions="{projectRP.currentItem.project.positions as Array}"
            />
    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:Canvas>
```

When I save the project, I do not get any errors or warnings.  However, when I attempt to output the values in the component, the projectPositions piece comes back as Null.

Anybody have any ideas?  I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of two days, and I'm completely stumped :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting `projectRP.currentItem.project.positions` as `Array` but it is `XMLList`. So after casting you have `null`.

Comment: is there any easy way to convert this XMLList into an array?  I tried creating a function with a for each loop, but it returns a length of 0 :(

Comment: You can iterate `XMLList` with `for each` loop the following way: `for each (var item:XML in myXMLList)`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch... turns out i had to nest a for each within the for each you mentioned because i have a "<positions>" tag around the group of positions.  If i did do this, a request of Alert.show(String(item.position.startOffset)); would show each and every offset (tags included).